# python loop over continuously expanding list

Tags: python, list, numpy

I have a list containing values (tuples in my case) - in the beginning there is 1 element. I need to loop over a list and for the last value in the list apply some computations, which will provide me with the next list element. After that I need to concatenate those lists and using the last value of the list compute next element. And so on...

How can it be done? NumPy also can be used.

Now I do like this, but it does not work

```
while True:
    lst = [1]
    print(lst)
    for i in range(len(lst)):
        elem = lst[-1]
        new = elem + 10 // dummy computations
        lst.append(new)
```

Comment: Please give a small example or first attempt, so that we can understand what you need.

Comment: Are you talking about lazy lists?

Comment: added code of what I do now

Comment: please explain why you need to loop over the list, if you only need the last element in it...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

How is this for a start?

```
def f(x):
    return 2*x+1

a = [ 1 ]
while len(a) < 8:
   x = a[-1]
   y = f(x)
   a.append(y)

a
=> [1, 3, 7, 15, 31, 63, 127, 255]
```

Comment: For such a simple function, you probably would want to do something like: `idx = np.arange(8-1); x = 1; a = [x]; a.extend(list(2**(idx+1)*x + np.cumsum(2**idx)))`. But this may be hard for generic functions.

Answer (score 3):

If you just want to loop through the list later, you can build a generator:

```
def f(elem):
    return elem + 10

def lst(init):
    yield init
    while True:
        next = f(init)
        yield next
        init = next
```

This goes on forever, so be sure your loop has some break in it:

```
for i in lst(1):
    print i
    if i > 100:
        break
```

prints:

```
1
11
21
31
41
51
61
71
81
91
101
```